# Entity Framework, Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions, Version=3.1.0.0

Tags: c#, .net, azure, entity-framework-core, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to build an API .net core and hosted in Azure App Service. The setup consists of a couple of projects but 2 have Entity Framework. 1. DataAccess proj there I have the EF context, migrations, etc. and 2 my web app context is in the DI

My problem:

```
Application '/LM/W3SVC/..../ROOT' with physical root 'D:\home\site\wwwroot\' hit unexpected managed exception, exception code = '0xe0434352'. First 30KB characters of captured stdout and stderr logs:
Unhandled exception. System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions, Version=3.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=.....'. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions, Version=3.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=.....'
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(String[] args)
   at Name.Name.Program.CreateHostBuilder(String[] args)
```

I looked at all the things on the internet and I cannot figure it out.
I was adding Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions 3.1.0 removing some dll, added AutoGenerateBindingRedirects, GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType in one PropertyGroup seperate and all in vain. **The funny part is that locally it works but when I deploy it to azure it doesn't.**

1 DataAccess csproj

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  
  <PropertyGroup>
  <AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
  <GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>true</GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>
</PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="5.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="5.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration" Version="6.0.1" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Name.Model\Name.Model.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

2 web app csproj

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <GenerateDocumentationFile>True</GenerateDocumentationFile> 
  </PropertyGroup>
  
  <PropertyGroup>
  <AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
  <GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>true</GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>
</PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Azure.Storage.Files.Shares" Version="12.9.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="LazyCache.AspNetCore" Version="2.4.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights" Version="2.20.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore" Version="2.20.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer" Version="3.1.23" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="5.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="5.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions" Version="6.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger" Version="6.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen" Version="6.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI" Version="6.3.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Name.BusinessLogic\Name.BusinessLogic.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Name.DataAccessLayer\Name.DataAccessLayer.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>


</Project>
```

Comment: Did you try to publish application and then install using the setup.exe folder?  A Net application will not work unless that same version of Net is installed on build and deploy machines AND the versions of Windows dlls are the same.  Setup updates the windows dlls on deploy machine so app will run.

Comment: @jdweng you were right I had mistakes in my build pipelines/scripts
added to pipeline yaml
msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:DesktopBuildPackageLocation="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)\Name.zip" /p:DeployIisAppPath="Default Web Site"'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

and changed in the release -> Agent pool -> into Azure Pipelines

now it works :)